# Is there a way to filter through html_nodes with html_attributes?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I started to use R and have a question, i'm trying to collect a list of prices of a html page. Here's an exemple of what i'm able to get when i ask R for prices

```
<h3 class="item_price" itemprop="price" content="16450">                                        16 450&nbsp;€
</h3>
```

I know that i have exactly 35 prices that follows `<h3 class="item_price" itemprop="price" content="1234">`
Is it possible to filter through h3 elements and attribute class="item_price" and then ask for content attribute value ?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes its possible - source: rvest::html_attr documentation

```
movie <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
cast <- html_nodes(movie, "#titleCast span.itemprop")
html_text(cast)
html_name(cast)
html_attrs(cast)
html_attr(cast, "class")
```

In case you have a more sophisticated question, please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: What is the expected output of this code? I get `> html_text(cast)
character(0)
> html_name(cast)
character(0)
> html_attrs(cast)
list()
> html_attr(cast, "class")
character(0)`